# How do you declare a Predicate Delegate inline?

Tags: c#, delegates

So I have an object which has some fields, doesn't really matter what.
I have a generic list of these objects.

```
List<MyObject> myObjects = new List<MyObject>();
myObjects.Add(myObject1);
myObjects.Add(myObject2);
myObjects.Add(myObject3);
```

So I want to remove objects from my list based on some criteria.
For instance, `myObject.X >= 10.`
I would like to use the `RemoveAll(Predicate<T> match)` method for to do this.

I know I can define a delegate which can be passed into RemoveAll, but I would like to know how to define this inline with an anonymous delegate, instead of creating a bunch of delegate functions which are only used in once place.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

There's two options, an explicit delegate or a delegate disguised as a lamba construct:

explicit delegate

```
myObjects.RemoveAll(delegate (MyObject m) { return m.X >= 10; });
```

lambda

```
myObjects.RemoveAll(m => m.X >= 10);
```

---

Performance wise both are equal. As a matter of fact, both language constructs generate the same IL when compiled. This is because C# 3.0 is basically an extension on C# 2.0, so it compiles to C# 2.0 constructs

Answer (score 15):

The lambda C# 3.0 way:

```
myObjects.RemoveAll(m => m.x >= 10);
```

The anonymous delegate C# 2.0 way:

```
myObjects.RemoveAll(delegate (MyObject m) {
   return m.x >= 10;
});
```

And, for the VB guys, the VB 9.0 lambda way:

```
myObjects.RemoveAll(Function(m) m.x >= 10)
```

Unfortunately, VB doesn't support an anonymous delegate.

Comment: Why should VB want anonymous delegates when it has lambdas?

And yes, the next version will have multi-line lambdas and lambdas that don't return a value (= `Sub`s).

Comment: Because of the reasons you just stated - multiline statements, and functions that don't return a value. Good to know it'll be in the next version, but C# has had it since 2005.

Answer (score 11):

```
  //C# 2.0
  RemoveAll(delegate(Foo o){ return o.X >= 10; });
```

or

```
  //C# 3.0
  RemoveAll(o => o.X >= 10);
```

or

```
  Predicate<Foo> matches = delegate(Foo o){ return o.X >= 10; });
  //or Predicate<Foo> matches = o => o.X >= 10;
  RemoveAll(matches);
```

Answer (score 2):

Predicate is a delegate which takes an param and returns a boolean.

We can do the same in following ways

1) **Using inline Lambda expression**

```
RemoveAll(p=> p.x > 2);
```

2) **Using anonymous function**

```
RemoveAll(delegate(myObject obj){

  return obj.x >=10;
})
```

3) **Using Predicate delegate**

```
Predicate<myObject> matches = new Predicate<myObject>(IsEmployeeIsValid);
RemoveAll(matches);

Predicate<Foo> matches = delegate(Foo o){ return o.X >= 20; });
RemoveAll(matches);
```

3) **Declaring a delegate explicitily and pointing to a function**

```
public delegate bool IsInValidEmployee (Employee emp);

IsInValidEmployee invalidEmployeeDelegate = new IsInValidEmployee(IsEmployeeInValid);
myObjects.RemoveAll(myObject=>invalidEmployeeDelegate(myObject);
```

// Actual function

```
public static bool IsEmployeeInValid(Employee emp)
{
    if (emp.Id > 0 )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```